# Запрос к массиву Postgre SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос, jsonb

В базе `CreditPrograms` есть колонка "Data" содержащая jsonb объект такого вида:

```
{
  "RegionsActivity":[
    23
  ]
}
```

Я хочу произвести поиск по массиву `RegionsActivity`:

```
select *
from "CreditPrograms"
WHERE 23 = ANY("Data"->'RegionsActivity')
```

Данный синтаксис был взять с оф документации https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/arrays

но postgre выдает ошибку:

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "array"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив какого-то типа в `postgresql` и массив в документе JSON - это разные вещи.

Для json массивов из чисел у `postgresql` поддержка всё ещё довольно слабая и я не вижу чего-то сильно подходящего для задачи [в списках операторов или функций](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). Выполнить задачу минимально возможно через подзапрос с `jsonb_array_elements_text`:

```
select *
from "CreditPrograms"
WHERE exists(
  select from jsonb_array_elements_text("Data"->'RegionsActivity') el
  where el = '23'
)
```

Если необходима производительность запроса (вместо просмотра всей таблицы), то необходимо перерабатывать схему данных. Либо, если это невозможно, создать `immutable` хранимку преобразующую `"Data"->'RegionsActivity'` в массив числового типа, построить `gin` индекс и искать по этой хранимке.

---

Возможно вам больше подойдёт стороннее расширение [`jsquery`](https://github.com/postgrespro/jsquery).

Comment: Очень жаль, спасибо Вам.